# jump link not working in asp.net iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I am using the iframe in  asp.net page.Page name is Home.aspx and iframe id name is frame1. I frame have some html design with more header. I want to search the header using quick link.But it's working fine in HTML page not in asp.net page. Please help me to do this..

My code is here..

```
  <tr>
       <td>
          &nbsp; 1. <a href="#Employment Application"target="_parent">Employment Application</a>
       </td>
        <td>
          &nbsp; 2. <a href="#Transfer and Reassignment">Transfer and Reassignment</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            &nbsp; 3. <a href="#Non-Discrimination">Non-Discrimination</a>
         </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use spaces in your links. Just run all the words together and make sure the 'a name' tag matches that. Also you need a space between the href and target attributes on your first link.

Comment: can you send some example code..

Answer (score 0):

As Billy Moat said, the problem is likely that you are using spaces in your `href` attributes for the links.  This is not allowed, so you should change your `href`s **and the IDs of the elements that they are referencing** to not include spaces:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp; 1. <a href="#EmploymentApplication"target="_parent">Employment Application</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp; 2. <a href="#TransferAndReassignment">Transfer and Reassignment</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp; 3. <a href="#Non-Discrimination">Non-Discrimination</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```